# Using Objects vs Local Variables & Parameters in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Just wondering what is the most effective way to write some code for the following scenarios...

I have a simple web form that collects data and then inserts it into a database. Which of the following examples is most efficient or better and why?

I am currently using a version of the first scenario (but with more fields and proper HTML Encoding etc.). I find it cleaner to read, but it is going overboard or wasting performance and quality code?

**Code Scenario 1**

```
void GetData() {
    FormResponse myFormResponse = new FormResponse();
    FormResponse.Name = txtName.Text;
    FormResponse.Email = txtEmail.Text;
    FormResponse.Message = txtMessage.Text;

    StoreData(myFormResponse);
}

void StoreData(FormResponse myFormResponse) {
    ... //Database connection code

    DbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", myFormResponse.Name);
    DbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", myFormResponse.Email);
    DbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", myFormResponse.Message);

    ...//More DB handler code
}

Public Class FormResponse {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

**Code Scenario 2**

```
void GetData() {

    string strName = txtName.Text;
    string strEmail = txtEmail.Text;
    string strMessage = txtMessage.Text;

    StoreData(strName, strEmail, strMessage);
}

void StoreData(string strName, string strEmail, string strMessage) {
    ... //Database connection code

    DbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", strName);
    DbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", strEmail);
    DbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", strMessage);

    ...//More DB handler code
}
```

Comment: Why is a method named `GetData` which actually stores data?

Comment: I like the first approach better too, and don't think there will be a serious performance hit, but the only way to be sure is to measure it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter `GetData()` gets the data from the form and passes it to `StoreData()` which inserts it into the database.

Comment: @SamuelMacLachlan: Yes, but why does a method `GetData` calls `StoreData`? Even if you're the only developer it's error-prone  in case you forget it. A getter just returns something. You could let it return `FormResponse` which you could pass to `StoreData` afterwards.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Hmm good point. I can now see the logic in calling the methods that way instead. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always think about the long-run when coding things like this, always make your programs as extensible as possible, as well as readable for future developers. Yes, always think about performance, but in this case, the performance difference (if any) is very trivial.

Always code with object orientation in mind, and thus the first approach would be my ideal choice, with the FormResponse object being in a Models class. Imagine if you have two forms, you can re-use this object easily, as well as the function call still being applicable if you need to send in any extra data attached to this individual object, i.e. private function(objectName) will never change.

As I say, always think about extensibility in everything you do. What if you need your name formatting in the response function, simply do:

```
public FormRespose() 
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public string FirstName { // use Name here to get first name from it, or turn uppercase, lowercase, whatever }
}
```

Hopefully this should be enough to make my point.